# List view filter callback

Tags: 2013, javascript, list-view, view

Is there a way to catch the event fired alter filtering a list view webpart? (fintere using the default filter)

I need to get the items in the view after a filter has been applied.
Is there a sort of callback?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use Client Side Rendering (JS Link) and the `OnPostRender` property. When you use a filter in the list view it will trigger the `OnPostRender` again. Check out this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views) for more information.

Code example:

```
(function () {
    var overrideCtx = {};

     overrideCtx.OnPostRender = [];
     overrideCtx.OnPostRender.push(function()
     {
        console && console.log("Filter done");
     });
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
})();
```