# Lists sorting by column header click does not trigger OnPostRender event

Tags: sorting

I'm using Client Side Rendering (JS Link) and according to this answer an OnPostRender event should be triggered whenever a list view column is resorted from a column header click:

[List view filter callback](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/136051/list-view-filter-callback?newreg=ce85f7b498ec496e8c824deb2f1662bd)

But I'm not seeing that.

OnPostRender is triggered when the page loads but not after the page is loaded and you click a list column header to resort it. I'm looking for OnPostRender or another callback I can use after the list has been resorted.